# Where can one find the expression for the origin of the Hamiltonian of the Kerr nonlinear interaction in an optical cavity?

Tags: quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

Recently, I was reading some papers about Kerr media in a cavity, and I found that almost all articles give the Hamiltonian as
$$H=K\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}.$$
In order to determine its origin, I searched some papers and books, but they are the same ($H=K\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$ or $H=K\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}\hat{a}$).

In [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.105.023719) article, it says "However, this term results from neglecting the counter-rotating terms [rotating wave approximation (RWA)] in the interaction terms...", but there are no citations.

So, where can one find the origin of this expression?

Answer (score 3):

As with all quantum theories, the quantum theory of a Kerr medium comes from a quantization of the classical theory. In a nonlinear medium, the electric flux density $\mathbf{D}$ can be expanded in terms of the electric field $\mathbf{E}$. In tensor notation the expansion is
$$ D_a = \epsilon_0 (E_a +\chi_{ab} E_b +\chi_{abc} E_b E_c
 +\chi_{abcd} E_b E_c E_d + ... ) .$$
The third order term represents a Kerr medium. If you combine it with another $E_a$, as in the classical Hamiltonian, you get the nonlinear term in the classical Hamiltonian:
$$ H_i = \epsilon_0 \chi_{abcd} E_a E_b E_c E_d . $$
To get the equivalent term for the quantum theory, you need to replace the classical electric field with their quantum versions, which is something like
$$ \mathbf{E} = i \sum \mathcal{N} \left[ \vec{\eta}_s \hat{a}_s(\mathbf{k}) \exp(i\omega t-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}) 
- \vec{\eta}_s^* \hat{a}_s^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k}) \exp(-i\omega t+i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})\right] d^3k, $$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is a bunch of constants including $\hbar$.

When you expand the resulting expression and commute the ladder operators then you can discard some non-physical terms. One of the terms you'll end up with has the form $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$. However, you can commute the operators to produce different orders.

Comment: This answer is very clear, thank you very much! Do you know of any books that have a good describe of Kerr media?

Comment: No, if you find one, let me know.

Comment: [Here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/41/2/025102/pdf) me find some inforamtion about my question.